# R - whats the type of this object and how to work with it?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm lost with the following object in R:

```
# create a list of filenames
files <- list.files("directory", full.names = TRUE)

# read all files as csv
data <- lapply(files, function(x) (data.frame(read.csv(x))))
```

Thats fine, but I have no idea what the type of data is and how to get my hands on it. Lets have a look:

```
data[1]
[[1]]
       Date value1 value2 ID
1    2003-01-01      NA      NA  1
2    2003-01-02      NA      NA  1
...
```

Ok, that looks like a data frame (thats also what I intended when I did data.frame(read.csv(x))) -- I wanted a list of data frames. Unfortunately, when I ask

```
typeof(data[1])
[1] "list"
```

R claims data[1] to be a list. Why? I figured out now how that data[[1]] gives access to the data.frame as intended. But I could not figure out how to apply operations on the data frames packed in data. For instance, I would like to filter all elements from data which have more than 100 rows in the dataframe. I tried

```
lapply(data, Filter, f = function(x) (nrow(data.frame(x))>100))
```

but this just gives back a list of the same length as data which contains for instance

```
[[1]]
data frame with 0 columns and 1461 rows
```

Basically I have three questions:

1. Why do I get a list of lists instead of a list of data frames?
2. Could I convert this list of lists into, lets say a vector of data frames?
3. How could I subset the list in the way described above (for instance get all frames with more then 1000 rows)?

Comment: I don't think you need `data.frame` here (this is what probably what causes the problem). How about just `data <- lapply(files, read.csv)` ?

Comment: And for filtering, simply use `Filter(function(u) nrow(u)>100, data)`

Comment: May I recommend taking the time to read some R-manuals to learn about classes and sub-classes of objects?

Answer (score 0):

Ad1: 
This is pretty basic stuff: the `[` operator does not select a single element from a list - it returns a subset of a list. For a single element use `[[` or `$`. So the answer to the first question is: you *do* get a list of data frames.

Ad2: You can't have vectors of data frames.

Ad3: `lapply` needs a FUN argument. But even if used correctly, lapply will produce some output element for every input element in a list. For filtering use `Filter`, in your case: `Filter(function(x) nrow(x) > 100, data)`

Comment: Ok ... I do not really it. How, for instance get a vector with all value1 from data?

Comment: @DaLi You can merge the data frames from a list to a single data frame with `df1 <- do.call(rbind, data)` and to get `value1` column use `df1$value1` or `df1[["value1"]]`